# Word Bibliography Style - Remove space before brackets

Tags: xml, reference, ms-word, whitespace, bibliography

I am trying to create (to be honest, to modify) my own Word Bibliography Style.
I have already managed to remove the brackets from my references, so I can use them just plainly, e.g. Williams, 2000 instead of (Williams, 2000).
However, sometimes I want to put the citation within brackets. But when I insert a citation between brackets, a white space appears in front of the reference, e.g. ( Williams, 2000).
I am searching for the code in my xsl document responsible for adding this space. I definitely want to remove if.
Does someone have an idea?
(I've uploaded my xsl file here if needed https://mega.nz/#!qERgBQSI!AobTxN1rQ_CASqU_fc9SGlziRuQgnYuII1c_GslfwEg
) Thank you!

Comment: MS has built some logic into the Style sheets to insert a space if one is lacking before a citation; you'll need to either delete that logic or edit it so that it doesn't insert one after an opening parenthesis.

Comment: Yes, but where can I do it?

Comment: I'd have though it obvious you'd need to edit the Stylesheet. They're the XSL files found in: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office#\Bibliography\Style, where # is the Office version.

Comment: Yes, that is obvious that I need to edit that file (I attached my own above), but I still cannot find the line responsible for that extra space within the stylesheet...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with XSL stylesheet, but with inserting citation after left bracket.

If you insert citation first and later left bracket before the citation (field), the leading whitespace doesn't appear.

Comment: That’s true but when working with long documents at the end I usually hit refresh all citations to ensure that the newest data/versions are there. With the refresh, the space is put back and I need to re-delete them one by one.
Since I got no answer here I am using Zotero to manage citations. That has its own flaws (e.g. sometimes makes strange things with ctrl+z) but solves my current problem.